# What is the difference between deliver & deliver_now in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

There is not clear explanation between deliver & deliver_now in rails mailers.

if we use deliver_now it won't queue up for an active job. if we use deliver_later it will be executed by active_job (background job).

when deliver & deliver_now are not executed in the background, then what exactly the difference between them? I searched a lot but did not get a clear idea. between deliver and deliver_now.

is there any difference or both are the same

Answer (score 5):

They're the same. Use `deliver_now`, not `deliver`.

https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.9/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery/deliver

```rb
    def deliver #:nodoc:
      ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn(        `#deliver` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5. Use        `#deliver_now` to deliver immediately or `#deliver_later` to        deliver through Active Job..squish)

      deliver_now
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that #deliver_now is a wrapper for #deliver and uses #deliver under the hood in the [Rails source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/36c1591bcb5e0ee3084759c7f42a706fe5bb7ca7/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb#L123). There's no major difference. Both will work - even in Rails 6+ - but #deliver_now is preferred because it's more overt about what the code is doing / what is happening.

In practice, you almost always want to use #deliver_later and to use a background server like [Sidekiq](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq) with Redis, [GoodJob](https://github.com/bensheldon/good_job) (or [SolidQueue](https://github.com/basecamp/solid_queue) in Rails 8) - if I'm not mistaken #deliver_now can be blocking for a web request - so best to offload that to a background process to speed up your Rails application's response time for your users.